# Spring Security - Google OAuth 2.0 - UnknownHostException www.googleapis.com

Tags: spring-security, oauth-2.0, google-kubernetes-engine, spring-security-oauth2, google-oauth

I've implemented Google oauth login based on this tutorial: https://www.callicoder.com/spring-boot-security-oauth2-social-login-part-1/

It is working correctly when app is run locally. However, after deploying it on GKE, I'm unable to log in - flow fails with the following error:

```
error: [invalid_token_response] An error occurred while attempting to retrieve the OAuth 2.0 Access Token Response: I/O error on POST request for "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token": www.googleapis.com; nested exception is java.net.UnknownHostException: www.googleapis.com
```

Which comes from `OAuth2AccessTokenResponseClient`

As I said before, it's working fine when run on localhost and I'm unable to debug it.
The app is deployed with Ingress using a static IP. I've assigned that IP to my domain very recently. Domain is registered in Google APIs `Authorised redirect URIs`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that `kube-dns` pods dind't get up. I set up a preemptible cluster and added a taint to it's only node pool. That prevented `kube-dns` from starting:

```
Normal   NotTriggerScaleUp  61s (x22798 over 2d18h)  cluster-autoscaler  pod didn't trigger scale-up (it wouldn't fit if a new node is added): 1 node(s) had taints that the pod didn't tolerate
Warning  FailedScheduling   44s (x141 over 26h)      default-scheduler   0/1 nodes are available: 1 node(s) had taints that the pod didn't tolerate.
```

After removing the taint hostname got resolved

Answer (score 0):

Google APIs use the OAuth 2.0 protocol for authentication and authorization. Google supports common OAuth 2.0 scenarios such as those for web server, installed, and client-side applications. Please have a look at this [link](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2?_ga=2.101380609.-1619269284.1577743893).

We can follow the below steps for [obtaining OAuth 2.0](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2InstalledApp#obtainingaccesstokens) access tokens. 
Step 1: Generate a code verifier and challenge
Step 2: Send a request to Google's OAuth 2.0 server
Step 3: Google prompts user for consent
Step 4: Handle the OAuth 2.0 server response
Step 5: Exchange authorization code for refresh and access tokens

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. I know what the flow it and it's handled by spring-security. It clearly fails at step 5 due to some networking issue